# How to do this type of website log on: user enters "thisUser@mydomain.com" and is then prompted with login box?

Tags: php, authentication

I have only really seen this once before, and it was in use on a school website...

But basically the user had to enter headmaster@thisschool.com, they were then presented with a log in box. Once the user fills in the username and password, they are then directed to a private part of the website?

I intend to use this method to access my cms which is held out of the accessable web root.

Along with any input regarding my question, could someone provide some input as to the plus sides and down sides of using something like this to access your cms?

Comment: which framework you are using ?? asp.net ?? php? ruby?

Comment: sorry i'm not php guy, but i tagged qn for php, so some one will help you soon. i can give just an overview. you need to store user credential in database, and authorize them

Comment: @Ravi i already have a functional login system in place, so this would basically be an extension of that. Thank you for your input friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what framework you're using -- it sounds like you're referring to a "box" being like a dialog box? This is called HTTP authentication. What matters is your platform. Windows (IIS)/Apache, for example, are configured differently, but both can send headers so the browser prompts for username and password. Google HTTP authentication for your specific platform.

For example, Apache has .htaccess to help: http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/#sec12a

Comment: Thanks Matt that does sound like what i am looking for.